# Есть ли корректный способ обрабатывать тексты к кириллицей посредством awk?

Tags: linux, utf-8, кириллица, awk, консоль

Есть два файла:

> country.csv и president.csv

country.csv имеет два столбца: 1)Название страны; 2) Население

president.csv тоже два столбца: 1)Название страны; 2)Имя ее президента
В качестве разделителя используется точка с запятой. Оба файла в кодировке utf-8.

Надо получить третий файл (или дописать колонку в первый - не суть), где в одной строке будут находиться все три поля: Название страны; Количество населения; Имя президента.
Количество строк в файлах разное, т.е. некоторых стран может не быть как в первом так и во втором файле, т.е. просто отсортировать и затем вслепую присоединить столбец не получится. Необходимо именно по значению первой ячейки первого файла найти строку с этим значением во втором файле и взять значение из второй колонки этой строки.

Пытаюсь сделать это подобным скриптом:

```
    #!/bin/bash

while read LINE; do
        C_NAME=$(echo $LINE | cut -d";" -f1)
        awk -v country=$C_NAME -v line=$LINE -F";" '$1 == country {print line";"$2}' president.csv >>result.csv
done < country.csv
```

И получаю сообщение об ошибке:

```
    > awk: cmd. line:1: Албания 
    > awk: cmd. line:1: ^ invalid char '�' in expression
```

Как выйти из ситуации?

P.S.

```
$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: приложите, пожалуйста, к тексту вопроса (нажав [edit]), вывод программы *locale*

Comment: Ваш пример у меня работает, если переменные взять в кавычки `...country="$C_NAME" -v line="$LINE"...`

Comment: @aleksandr-barakin приложил

Comment: @PotroNik так скрипт отрабатывает без ошибок, но на выходе почему-то $2 оказывается в начале строки с разделителем перед собой, затирая несколько первых символов $LINE

Comment: @SebastianPereira, а если в скрипте указать `export LANG=C` после `#!/bin/bash` выводится аналогично?

Comment: @PotroNik, такой же результат, да

Comment: Причиной проблемы оказалась моя невнимательность и... некорректный символ завершения строки: \r\n вместо \n
Благодарю всех за проявленный интерес и прошу прощения.

Answer (score 6):

для такой простой задачи подойдёт и инструмент попроще: программа *join* из пакета программ *gnu/coreutils*.

файлы:

```
$ cat население 
бомбардия;100
муми-дол;50
$ cat президент 
бомбардия;кергуду
муми-дол;снусмумрик
```

объединить можно так:

```
$ join -t ';' население президент 
бомбардия;100;кергуду
муми-дол;50;снусмумрик
```

или в обратной последовательности:

```
$ join -t ';' президент население 
бомбардия;кергуду;100
муми-дол;снусмумрик;50
```

---

главное: содержимое файлов должно быть отсортировано. можно сделать это «на лету» (если в качестве оболочки/интерпретатора используется что-нибудь вроде *bash/zsh*):

```
$ join <(sort файл1) <(sort файл2)
```

Comment: Количество строк в обоих файлах должно быть одинаково? И первые столбцы после сортировки должны совпадать?
Если так, то join не подойдет, т.к. файлы невозможно привести к такому виду.

Comment: 1. нет. 2. нет.

Comment: попробовал сначала join <(sort country.csv) <(sort president.csv) - получилось так же, как с моим скриптом: $2 оказался в начале строки с разделителем перед собой, затерев несколько первых символов $LINE.
Затем попробовал join <(sort president.csv) <(sort country.csv) - на выходе получил country.csv с разделителем без первого столбца.

Comment: разделитель-то не забывайте указывать.